# Give an algebraic proof to show that $A$ and $B$, $(B^{c}\cup(B^{c} - A))^{c} = B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Give an algebraic proof to show that  $A$ and $B$, $(B^{c}\cup(B^{c} - A))^{c} = B$

This is a discrete mathematics set theory problem, of course. Right now, I have the following proof worked out:

> We wish to show that for all sets $A$ and $B$, $(B^{c}\cup(B^{c} - A))^{c} = B$. We
> will proceed algebraically.
>
> Distributing the compliment, $B \cup (B - A^{c})$.
>
> Under the set difference law, this can be written as $B \cup (B \cap A)$.
>
> Under the distributive law, this can be written as $(B \cup B) \cap A$.
>
> Under the identity law, $(B \cup B) = B$. Then $B \cap A$ is left.

I don't know what I did wrong, but I also don't know how $B \cap A$ could equal $B$. Any guidance?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B^{c}\cap A^{c}\subseteq B^{c}$, we may claim the desired result:

\begin{align*}
(B^{c}\cup(B^{c} - A))^{c} & = (B^{c}\cup(B^{c}\cap A^{c}))^{c} = (B^{c})^{c} = B
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I'm not quite sure I understand how we get from (B^c ∪(B^c ∩ A^c))^c to (B^c)^c, though. B compliment ∩ A compliment might be a subset of B compliment, if I'm understanding the notation correctly, but why does that allow us to disregard it?

Comment: @RadiantAine That is because $X\subseteq Y$ iff $X\cup Y = Y$. In the present case, $X = B^{c}\cap A^{c}$ and $Y = B^{c}$.

Answer (score 0):

For any set $S$ and any set $C$ it is clear that $S \cup (S - C)$ is $S$ itself because by the union you are returning back the elements of $S$ that you took out by $S - C$, so here in this case we have $S = B^c$ and $C=A$ and so we'll have $(B^c)^c$ which is $B$ itself.